# Cron to run every 2nd wednesday?

Tags: linux, cron

I need to find a way to cron a job so that it runs every second wednesday of the month.  Is this possible?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week) looks to provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: Yeah, but that question's about Tue, not Wed ;) The accepted answer is clever, though.

Comment: >> Yeah, but that question's about Tue, not Wed ;) The accepted answer is clever, though ... what is so hard to change Tue to Wed ?

Comment: 0 * * * 3 test $(date \+%u) -eq 3 && echo "start run me" try this. didn't paste to the answer because one liner question is pretty vague.

Answer (score 20):

My manpage for crontab (which I sadly can't seem to find online) gives the following example:

```
# Run on every second Saturday of the month
0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
```

Adapting this to your purposes...

```
0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 3 && job.sh
```

Comment: To anyone looking to edit this answer, the reason you don't just use the day of week field is that if both day of month and day of week are restricted (ie, aren't `*`), the command will run when _either one_ matches.

Comment: crontab manpage: http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5

Comment: I found that I had to escape the %u, so: `date +\%u`

Answer (score 5):

For CentOS 7 servers, this seems to be the syntax that works for me. Please note the spaces around the `[` and `]`. That took a while for me to figure out.

This runs the `test.sh` file at 13:07 / 1:07PM on the second Wednesday of the month. 
(0=Sunday, 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, 3=Wednesday, etc.)

```
07 13 8-14 * * [ `date +\%u` = 3 ] &&  /root/scripts/test.sh
```

Comment: Working for me on CentOS 8 Stream too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week) answer, you could do:

```
00 12 * * Wed expr `date +\%d` \> 7 \& `date +\%d` \< 15 >/dev/null && runJob.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using cron on its own, but you could call a script once a week that does the test:

In crontab, run second_wed.sh at 12.00 every Wednesday:

```
0 12 * * 3 /home/you/bin/second_wed.sh
```

In second_wed.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#get day of month
day_of_month=`date +%d`

#if this day is between 7th and 15th day of the month = 2nd week
if [ $day_of_month -gt 7 -a $day_of_month -lt 15 ]; then
  # Call your program here instead of 'ls'…
  ls
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire at 10:15 AM on the third Friday of every month: `0 15 10 ? * 6#3`

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Comment: That's so cool. Too bad it isn't supported on most common Linux distros :/

Answer (score 0):

```
7 13 8-14 * 3 /home/you/bin/second_wed.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
37 2 * * 3 [[ $(($(date +%-V -d '20220208') % 2)) -eq 0 ]] && /path/to/script
```

This will run the script on Wednesday of every even week of the year. Unfortunately you may hit one week delay when the year has 53 weeks.

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid running an external script by using a combination of the day of week trick plus the weekday:

```
# Run on every second Wednesday of the month
0 4 8-14 * Wed job.sh
```

This also avoids running another external program.  The 8-14 selects all days that match the second week of the month.  Then it filters out just that Wednesday.

Comment: according to this: [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_4_8-14_*_Wed) , `cron` will execute the task every day: 8,9,10,11,...,14 at 4AM. So, it is 7 invocations instead of one. I don't want to test it in production))

Comment: @maxkoryukov it says "“At 04:00 on every day-of-month from 8 through 14 and on Wednesday.” will execute only once, when its Wed and the day in the range 8-14.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla friend, please check the "next invocations" section. Or run something with this settings on your host.

Comment: Or better yet, just read the man page:  Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields — day of  month,  and  day  of week.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., don't start with *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time.  For example,``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.

Comment: In CentOS 8 Stream this certainly didn't work for me - as others have said it tries to run every date specified in the third column.